# Losing user cookies and session data after being redirected from payment gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, payment-gateway

I am using ASP.net MVC5 for my e-commerce project . I am not using any SSL . 
 I have also successfully integrated the payment gateway. The problem i am facing is that while i am posting data to the payment gateway it process the payment and send backs the response to our web application action method the user gets logged out i.e. User.idenity sets back to null .

I think it occurs beacuse of HTTP to HTTPS connection as every gateway uses https as a security. and after getting redirected to https it removes all the cookies and session data.

But I don't want to use https connection in order to retain the User login session . Please tell me how to retain my user signin state after it gets redirected back from payment gateway.

Comment: HTTPS all the way is the best course of action, especially if you are even near any payment processing. But I don't think this is the reason for loosing user auth - user is authenticated by cookie, not by session. Have you checked what happens with the auth cookie in Fiddler when you loose authentication?

Comment: Did you found out what caused this?

Comment: User.identity sets back to null

Comment: Any possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537150/asp-net-losing-session-upon-redirection-from-ccavenue-payment-gateway) I have faced similar issue while integrating CC avenue payment gateway.
To fix the issue, I have set the cookie domain name something like this `<httpCookies domain="localhost" httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="false" />` with sessionstate cookieSameSite="None". This has worked perfectly.

Comment: Can you please add a lot more description here?   For example how does setting the cookie domain fix the loss of session issue?

Comment: I found in my case just adding <sessionState timeout="30" cookieSameSite="None"/> in system.web in the web.config file fixed the problem.

Comment: usually this happens if your redirected to cross domains, in my case I was talking to some other domain and after some time control gets back to my domain. So the sessions are getting lost - @nuander

Comment: i am getting same error and have also tried this
session state and httpcookies tags but still getting the same error did you guys got the solution for this ?

Comment: @MuhammadAfnan - what is exact problem ?

Comment: @hemanthgali when I come back to my website from third party payment gateway I lost all my cookies and sessions. I have tried all these tags and values but the issue remains the same!