# ASP.NET losing session upon redirection from CCAvenue payment gateway

Tags: session-cookies, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am using ASP.net webforms and successfully integrated the payment gateway. The problem I'm facing is that while I'm posting data to the payment gateway it process the payment and send backs the response to our web application and user gets logged out i.e. because user session getting cleared and sets back to null .I thought this occurs because of HTTP to HTTPS connection as every gateway uses https as a security. and after getting redirected to https it removes all the cookies and session data.

Later I have run the solution by enabling SSL in IIS express to make sure that the redirection happens from https to https, but still the problem persists.
Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Please check for answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755885/losing-user-cookies-and-session-data-after-being-redirected-from-payment-gateway/60556673#60556673)
This worked for me.

Comment: I found in my case just adding <sessionState timeout="30" cookieSameSite="None"/> in system.web in the web.config file fixed the problem.